# golang mobile access file system

Tags: go, gomobile

How can i access the device system in gomobile?

Is there a way to interact with the native libs?

Like this:

```
package xy

import(
  "Foundation"// ios libraray
)

// Do some stuff with the Foundation package
func Test(){

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Take a look at Reverse Bindings here; https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gobind

To summarise, you import the Android/ObjectiveC library and are good to go.

The example they give;

`import "ObjC/Foundation/NSDate
 d := NSDate.Date()`

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: side question, how can i detect for which platform i run the build process? That i have only one codebase for both platforms, i write a function for ios and the other for java and the compiler compiles only the ios function for ios. Is there a ENV or something like this for a conditional statement?

Comment: Would need to test it but i *think* runtime.GOOS should tell you.

Comment: Just want to confirm; `if runtime.GOOS == "android"` is a functional env check. I assume "ios" would be the string on that platform (but have not checked).